# Matlab: Creating maps of groups and indicies of duplicates in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, grouping, duplicates

I have two Matlab arrays A(containing groups of numbers) and B(containing values that belong to the groups in A), there are repeats in array A

```
A = [1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 4] 
B = [1 2 3 3 5 4 4 1 6 7 8]
```

Now i would like to get the following two maps:

```
 C = ['1': {1,2,3}, '2': {3,5}, '3':{4}, '4':{1,6,7,8}]
```

where C gives a map with the group number as index and related values in that particular group.

```
D = ['1':{2,4},'2':{1},'3':{4},'4':{1}]
```

Where D gives a map with the group number from A as index. The values are the group numbers from A for which there are repeated values in B for that particular sub group.

What is the most efficient way of dealing with this problem? Are maps a good data structure to store this kind of data. I know the first one can be dealt with a for loop which i would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how you get to `D`.

For `C`, you can use `accumarray`:

```
C = accumarray(A,B,[],@(x){x})
```

`C{1}` is `[1 2 3]`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. D contains the groups which share the same values as a particular group. an example would be if you consider A as polygons, B as the vertices, then D will be the neighboring polygons sharing vertices with a particular polygon.